# Simultaneous Completion of Child Processes and Resolutions of Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, parent-child, child-process

**tl;dr: A function I wrote creates several child processes, which resolve a promise when they submit their data in a message. Although the function wraps all these promises in a Promise.All, the function will return abruptly, and the promise.all neither resolves nor rejects even though all of the processes finish without errors. Any ideas why this is happening?**

To speed up a data collecting process, I had a parent process take some input data (dates to be queried in SQL databases to be exact) and send it off to some number of child processes in equal sized chunks, waiting for the children to finish processing their data by wrapping their results in a large promise.

While this works for smaller datasets, for larger ones, the parent promise would simply return to the command line-neither resolving nor rejecting or even continuing the function. After looking at a few logs, it seems that while all of the child processes correctly process and send their data, the parent doesn't receive the results of a few (ie 2 out of the 10) process. The missed messages occur near the end of the data processing (when several child processes are completing and sending messages at about the same time)

Abbreviated code:

```
// main function
function createArray(i,j) // returns an array of i empty arrays, each of length j
function chunkify(a, n, balanced) // divides array a into n chunks (balancing them in size if true) returning an array of chunks

function kidcollector(snaptimes,course) {
  var done = 1;
  var numchild  = 10
  const chunked = chunkify(snaptimes,numchild,true);

  // array of numchild promises to be resolved upon arrival of data
  var collectedPromises = _.times(numchild).map(i => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var child = child_process.fork('./child.js');
      // send chunk of data to each child 
      child.send({
        times:chunked[i],
        c:course
      });

      child.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Child error.');
        reject(err)
      });

      child.on('message', function(m) {
        if (m.err) {
          console.log('Got error from '+ m.child, m.err);
          reject(m.err);
        } else {
          console.log('recieved data from ' + m.child + '! ' + done + ' out of ' + numchild);
          done++;
          resolve(m.data);
        }

      });
    });
  })

  return Promise.all(collectedPromises)
    .then(results => {
      // compile all data into one array then return it
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("One of the kids messed up:", err);
    })
};

// child.js, a separate file

const connString = // it's a secret!
const client = new Client(connString);
client.connect();

client.on('error', (err) => {
 console.error('Client error:', err.stack)
})

process.on('exit', (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(process.pid + ' has recieved error:', err);
  client.end(() => console.log(process.pid + ' has disconnected on process end', err));
})

process.on('disconnect', (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(process.pid + ' has recieved error:', err);
  client.end(() => console.log(process.pid + ' has disconnected on process disconnect'));
})

process.on('message', function(m) {
  collector(m.times,m.c,process.pid) // async function which compiles data across SQL databases
  .then(async function(subdata) {
    console.log("all done");
    await process.send({
      child: process.pid,
      data: subdata
    });
    await process.disconnect();
  })
  .catch(async function(err) {
    console.log("FAILED IN CHILD", err)
    await process.send({
      child: process.pid,
      err: err
    });
    await process.disconnect();
  })
});
```

So after running as expected for some time, near the end of the data processing, the log looks as follows:

```
all done // child says they're done
recieved data from 5486! 5 out of 10 // parent has received their data
5486 has disconnected on process disconnect // child disconnects
5481 processing snaptime #35 at 2017-07-31T20:26:40.322Z // child is now processing a new time from their given array
all done
recieved data from 5478! 6 out of 10
5478 has disconnected on process disconnect
5483 processing snaptime #34 at 2017-07-31T20:26:51.065Z
5485 processing snaptime #35 at 2017-07-31T20:27:01.876Z
all done // child says they're done
5477 has disconnected on process disconnect // child disconnects, but parent hasn't received data
all done
recieved data from 5481! 7 out of 10 // all good here
5481 has disconnected on process disconnect
5483 processing snaptime #35 at 2017-07-31T20:27:47.834Z
all done
5485 has disconnected on process disconnect // didn't receive message here
all done
recieved data from 5483! 8 out of 10
5483 has disconnected on process disconnect
hansy@Hansys-MacBook-Air ~/Documents/GitHub // and we're at the command line...?
```

On promise.all() resolution, the code should log the run time, and on rejection, it should log that one of children messed up, and its error.

Any ideas as to what's going on and/or how to resolve this issue, especially since it only occurs with larger datasets? (I am using node v8.0.0 with 10 child processes)

Comment: You need to condense your question. Otherwise it is simply too much for anyone to be willing to analyze it.

Comment: I think that using the child process not good idea at all for working with promises. Because parent process waits for a child process as child process also can wait for a message from the parent if it has such a listener. As you know such messages can be a lot and it hard to understand when the promise must be resolved. In contrast with worker threads that do not wait for anything. You can pass workerData to the worker and get a reasonable answer from it. You can check example with Promise and Worker in the documentation about worker threads (btw child_process doc does not have such examples)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that [`process.send`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) does not return a promise you could `await`, but instead takes an (optional) callback. So your `disconnect` call won't wait for the message to be sent.

Your parent process just finished when no more events are in the queue to be processed, even when the promise was not settled yet. Something you will want to listen for is the [`exit` event](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) of the child process, not only the `error` one. When you `reject` on that, you make sure that your `Promise.all` will always settle regardless what the child processes do.

I recommend

```
// parent
…
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const child = child_process.fork('./child.js');
  child.on('error', reject);
  child.on('exit', reject);
  child.on('message', resolve); // should happen before exit

  child.send({
    times: chunked[i],
    c: course
  });
}).then(function(m) {
  if (m.err) {
    console.log(`received error from #${i} (${m.child})`, m.err);
    throw m.err;
  } else {
    console.log(`received data from #${i} (${m.child})`);
    return m.data;
  }
}, function(err) {
  console.log(`Got abort from #${i} (${m.child})`);
  throw err;
});
```

```
// child
…
process.on('message', function(m) {
  collector(m.times, m.c, process.pid) // async function which compiles data across SQL databases
  .then(function(subdata) {
    console.log(process.pid+" done");
    return {
      child: process.pid,
      data: subdata
    };
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(process.pid+" FAILED:", err)
    return {
      child: process.pid,
      err: err
    };
  }).then(function(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      process.send(data, function(err) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve();
      });
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(process.pid+" FAILED to send result", err)
  }).then(function() {
    process.disconnect();
  })
});
```